# Eclipse debug into the sources generated at runtime

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-jdt

I have a project that generates the sources for the class, then compiles the sources into the bytecode (with Eclipse compiler if that makes the difference), then loads the newly created class with the custom classloader. The class is then used as the regular Java class.

I use Eclipse, and I want to write the plugin for the debugger that will allow me to source-debug the generated code that is not physically present on disk. I need a hint, a starting point where to look for. A some sort of extension point that such plugin should use, or the name of the class in Eclipse Debugger that is responsible for locating sources for the bytecode.

I am sorry, if the question is somewhat vague, but I need a starting point to start digging.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following extension points:

- org.eclipse.debug.core.sourceLocators
- org.eclipse.debug.core.sourceContainerTypes
- org.eclipse.debug.core.sourcePathComputers
- org.eclipse.debug.ui.sourceContainerPresentations